# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable

Tags: android, exception, missing-data

i am using terminal [not eclipse]. i got following exception error, while i use `emulator.debug` successfully and installd successfully. But emulator show **`Unfortunatly app has stop`**. Then i run `$ adb logcat` it will display following.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:107)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
at com.example.trintwo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I got this error, Even I installed android support library and i checked `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` in `android/support/v7/appcompat/lib` path what will i do to clear this error.

Comment: How did you reference the library in your project?

Comment: i am using terminal. i download android-sdk-linux package. Extract and using.

Comment: I was having same problem (at least I had the same exception/stack-trace).  I'm using the [android-sbt-plugin](http://fxthomas.github.io/android-plugin/).  The problem went away by upgrading from version 0.7 to 0.7.1-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: please make sure you don't have duplicate libs

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using eclipse than just import the v7 compat library project into your work space and add it as a library to your project. Else if you are doing it from terminal than what you can do is put `android-support-v7-appcompat` library project (which you can find in `sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat`) in the same directory where is your project and add this line to your `project.properties` file.

```
android.library.reference.1=../android-support-v7-appcompat
```

Do not forget to add both jar files v4, v7 to your project as well.

Answer (score 15):

Make sure to do the following (from [Support Library Setup](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)):

> 1. Right-click the library project folder and select Build Path >
>      Configure Build Path.
> 2. In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to
>      the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on this
>      library project. For example, the appcompat project requires you to
>      export both the android-support-v4.jar and
>      android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files.
> 3. Uncheck Android Dependencies.

Comment: sorry ya i am using terminal not eclips. pls tell for terminal

Comment: @Mike How about studio users?

Answer (score 1):

AppCompat is a lib with resource. You cannot add the jar, cause this library uses resources. So you need to add a library project.

Follow [Adding Support Libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library) steps.

Answer (score -1):

1. Right-click the your project folder and select java Build Path >Libraries
2. whether .jar file of your library project is present or not
3. if not buld the correct path that contains .jar file

Comment: i am using terminal [not eclips]. pls explain abut in terminal command

Answer (score -2):

If you are using **Android Studio** then its quick easier, Please add **compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'** in dependencies in build.gradle.

```
dependencies {
       compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.+'
}
```