# Launch Error on Android Application

Tags: android

I keep getting this error:

```
12-02 17:34:55.648: E/AndroidRuntime(426): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
12-02 17:34:55.648: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:147)
12-02 17:34:55.648: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
12-02 17:34:55.648: E/AndroidRuntime(426):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
```

I have tried unimporting and reimporting android.support.v7.ActionBarActivity
I hope someone can guide me to what the error is

Comment: right click on your project and add support library to the android libraries

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900832/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcompat-rstyleable)