# Crashing Application Android V7

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Third question regarding this these are the other two: 
[Launch Error on Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27255644/launch-error-on-android-application?noredirect=1#comment42985075_27255644)
[Android Application Crashing on Launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27160432/android-application-crashing-on-launch)

I tried to import android v7 again by using the project source appcompat but it has given me more error than before
This is a section of the logcat it is too long to insert in to this

```
tyles_rtl.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:57: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:56: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingStart'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:61: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:paddingEnd'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:65: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_marginStart'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:69: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:layout_alignParentStart'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v17\styles_rtl.xml:70: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textAlignment'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:56: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textColorAlertDialogListItem'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textColorHighlightInverse'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:55: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textColorLinkInverse'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:27: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:28: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:107: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textColorAlertDialogListItem'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:104: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textColorHighlightInverse'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:106: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textColorLinkInverse'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:77: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Dialog'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textColorAlertDialogListItem'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textColorHighlightInverse'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textColorLinkInverse'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:128: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:38: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:176: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:208: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textColorAlertDialogListItem'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:205: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textColorHighlightInverse'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:207: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:textColorLinkInverse'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:178: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:43: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:windowActionBar'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:336: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCopyDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:335: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCutDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:337: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModePasteDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:26: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCopyDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCutDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:27: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModePasteDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:28: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:343: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCopyDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:342: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCutDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:344: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModePasteDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:34: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCopyDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:33: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCutDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:35: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModePasteDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:36: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:350: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCopyDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:349: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCutDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:351: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModePasteDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:42: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCopyDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:41: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCutDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:43: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModePasteDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:44: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:357: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCopyDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:356: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCutDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:358: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModePasteDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:50: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCopyDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:49: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeCutDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:51: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModePasteDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:52: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeSelectAllDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:202: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:212: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:223: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:83: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:82: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:79: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:120: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:121: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:119: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:116: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:117: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-12-05 00:04:02 - Smart Food] C:\android-sdk-windows\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[201
```

Comment: It looks like you might need to clean and re-build your project to get the newly-imported jars in sync. Try that and see what happens

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help at all?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio? Can you tell me what the minimum sdk version is? you can find it in the `Manifest.xml` file if you use Eclipse or in `Build.gradle` for Android Studio

Comment: The minimum sdk is 9

Comment: 1.) try make a clean workspace for it if you are new for materialdesign.
2.) try with target=android-21 or 20 in project-properties file.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse or Android Studio?