# Android: Eclipse error: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable

Tags: android

Recently I tried to compile my project but I am getting this error this error below. I have done the following:

- Right-click the library project folder and select Build Path > Configure Build Path.
- In the Order and Export tab, check the .jar files you just added to the build path, so they are available to projects that depend on this library project. For example, the appcompat project requires you to export both the android-support-v4.jar and android-support-v7-appcompat.jar files.
- Uncheck Android Dependencies.

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900832/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcompat-rstyleable)

but without success.

I appreciate any help.

**Error:**

```
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342): Process: com.bustracker, PID: 2342
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:147)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:138)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:123)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at com.bustracker.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:12)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.bustracker-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     ... 17 more
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):         ... 18 more
06-16 10:11:57.787: E/AndroidRuntime(2342):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

**Screenshot 1**

[image]

**Screenshot 2**

[image]

Comment: Can you try to add appcompat-v7 project in `Project properties` =>`Android`=>`Add library`

Comment: I checked it and it is already added

Comment: can you add screenshot ? Try to check appcompat R file.

Comment: Please see my updated question. What do you mean with appcompat R file? where to find it?